# Python 3.7: a new behaviour of dir()

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've just installed Python 3.7 and faced an error with dir() in `inspect` module. Please consider this minimum example.

1) Create a module `testdir` that has one line:

```
__dir__ = 'bla'
```

2) in python:

```
import testdir
dir(testdir)
```

results in this error in Python 3.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

and runs normally in Python 3.6:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

I understand that dir() expects `__dir__` to be a function but in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) this is not a must but rather a condition and the docs provide no difference in respect to 3.x vs 3.7. Why the behaviour is different? Is it a bug or a feature?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-562-customization-of-access-to-module-attributes

Comment: deceze: thanks for the link! It explains. The implementation of that PEP 562 should check if `__dir__` is callable, but its too late now, I have to work on this 'improvement'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant PEP ([PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/)) actually contains the specification:

> The `__dir__` function should accept no arguments, and return a list of strings that represents the names accessible on module:
>
> ```
> def __dir__() -> List[str]: ...
> ```
>
> If present, this function overrides the standard dir() search on a module.

The difference is that `__dir__` in a module was simply ignored until Python 3.7. Given that double underscore names **must** be used according to Pythons specification it's not necessary to include a deprecation (for the changed behavior) there because `__dir__` as string was simply not according to the specification.

Comment: still, the implementation could have checked if `__dir__` is callable

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.7 now also allows [`__dir__` to be defined on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-562-customization-of-access-to-module-attributes). Previously it was simply ignored. The conditional part is that *if* `__dir__` is defined, it *must* be a callable, but it is *not required to be defined*.